# How do I keep track of a user's guesses in Python? attempts= attempts + 1 is not working

Tags: python

I need to keep track of the number of guesses a user inputs in a simple guessing game.

I have tried using attempts= 0 and then setting attempts to = attempts + 1. Even when I do this, the code will print "You have guessed in 1 attempts" even when the user has guessed in more attempts than one.

Code:

```
attempts = 0;
print("Hello, welcome to the game. You will be choosing a number 
between 1 and 100. You can only guess up to 10 times.")

for tries in range(tries_allowed):
    print("You only get 10 tries.")
    break 

while attempts < 10:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number"));
    attempts_used= attempts + 1;
    if guess > random_number:
            print("Guess is too high, try a smaller number");
    elif guess < random_number:
            print("Guess is too low, try a higher number");
    elif guess == random_number:
            attempts_used=str(attempts_used)
            print("Correct- you win in", attempts_used, "guesses");
            exit();
else:
    if tries_allowed == 10:
       print("You failed to guess in time")

my_list= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
my_list.append(attempts_used)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: You do not need to use `;` in python.

Comment: You have 2 distinct variables, `attemps` and `attemps_used`. `attemps` remains constant, with value `0` and `attemps_used` takes value `1` .... use only 1 variable and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up your code a bit, shows the `+=` counting method working for your script.
As others have said, the original code is creating an entirely new variable `attempts_used` that is simply `attempts + 1`, and `attempts` remains 0.

It could also be `attempts = attempts + 1`, `+=` means the same thing.

To make a `int` a `str` in python for printing purposes, it does not need to be stored to a separate variable, just call `str()` around it, unless you plan to use the string separately.

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(1,100)

attempts = 0
tries_allowed = 10
print("Hello, welcome to the game. You will be choosing a number between 1 and 100")

print("You only get " + str(tries_allowed) + " tries.")

my_list = []

while attempts < tries_allowed:
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number: "))
    if guess in my_list:
        print("You have already guessed " + str(guess))
        continue
    attempts += 1
    my_list.append(guess)
    if guess > random_number:
            print("Guess is too high, try a smaller number")
    elif guess < random_number:
            print("Guess is too low, try a higher number")
    elif guess == random_number:
            print("Correct- you win in", str(attempts), "guesses")
            break
else:
    if attempts == 10:
       print("You failed to guess in time")

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate you cleaning up my code. Do you know how I would print a brief message like "you already guessed that" if a user already guessed a certain number?

Comment: Added it to the code example, `continue` means go to the next iteration of the loop, since `attempts` was not incremented before the `continue`, it does not count the try.

Answer (score 2):

You never update the `attempts` variable, you've created a new one called `attempts_used`, you don't need to do this.

Just use `attempts` everywhere you're using `attempts_used`

Note: Whilst you're at it you should get rid of what is known as a "magic number", or a hard coded limit in your while loop

```
while attempts < tries_allowed:
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how I would print a brief message like "you already guessed that" if a user already guessed a certain number?

Comment: You should ask a new question if you need to but have a go first. You need a list to keep track of what has already been guessed and then check if the new guess already exists in that list

Answer (score 0):

Your "attemps" variable stays on 0, so attemps_used(attempts + 1) will always be 1. You have to merge both of the variables in only one in order to control it (attempts=attempts+1)

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how I would print a brief message like "you already guessed that" if a user already guessed a certain number?

Comment: Python has a syntax in which you can check if an element is in a list, so you can make an if like "if guess in my_list: print("You already tried that")"

Answer (score 0):

Code which also checks previous input and prints a message.

```
import random
# Hello World program in Python

attempts = 0
print("Hello, welcome to the game. You will be choosing a number between 1 and 100. You can only guess up to 10 times.")

random_number = random.randint(1, 101)
#print(random_number)
my_list= []

for tries in range(10):
    print("You only get 10 tries.")
    guess = int(input("Please guess a number: "))
    if guess in my_list:
        print("You already guessed this number!!")
    my_list.append(guess)
    attempts += 1

    if guess > random_number:
        print("Guess is too high, try a smaller number")
    elif guess < random_number:
        print("Guess is too low, try a higher number")
    else:
        print("Correct- you win in", tries + 1, "guesses")
        attempts = -1
        break


if attempts is 10 and attempts is not -1:   
    print("You failed to guess in time")
print("Attempts : ", my_list)
```